# How do I set JQuery Autocomplete to POST instead of GET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to set Jquery's Autocomplete HTTP submission method to POST instead of GET?

Comment: Also you can change MVC to allow GET. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350921/asp-net-mvc-2-failed-with-jquery-ajax-response#2350957

Comment: @Daveo: That's true, but we must be cautious about disabling a feature that was intended to protect us from browser vulnerability exploits.

Comment: Possibly of interest: A feature request (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5353), and an explanation for why it was rejected (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqueryui-autocomplete-post-option-for-remote-request#14737000002084408).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to the autocompleter that will allow you to set that. There is, however, a single place in the plugin code where the `$.ajax` function is called. There is no `type` option specified, which means that it will default to a GET request. You could modify the `$.ajax` call (which starts on line 361 of the latest version) to include a `type` option and set its value to "post":

```
$.ajax({ //line 361
    type: "post",
    ...
```

Comment: Modifying the source means you'll have trouble upgrading to the next version.

Comment: Also, the documentation says that `type: "POST"` is required. Probably, both are working but lowercase is bad style.

Answer (score 51):

Probably better to pass it in with the source parameter rather than setting it globally like this:

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.post("/AjaxPostURL", request, response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is a more complete version of $.post with additional data being passed:
<code>
    $(function() {
      var options = {    
        url: "/web/ajax.php?a=query-save-projects&w=app",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
         "args":$().crypt({method:"b64enc",source:JSON.stringify(_system) }),
         "url":document.URL
         }  
          }; 
    
      $( "#query-save-project-name" ).autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) { $.post(options["url"], options["data"], response, "json") },
         minLength: 2
         });
      });
</code>

Comment: This breaks if one of the requests fails. In that case `response` is never called which breaks the autocomplete plugin. Otherwise this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the

```
$.ajaxSetup( { type: "post" } );
```

before the call to autocomplete, and it will override the ajax call on the page.

Comment: This modifies *all* AJAX calls made through jQuery. This interacts badly with other code running on the page. Highly dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It's a REALLY bad idea to edit the source code because you'll lose your changes on the next upgrade of the widget. It's better to set the global type to "post" or pass in a request/response object.

Comment: Making a global POST setting modifies *all* AJAX calls made through jQuery. This interacts badly with other code running on the page. Highly dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I overwrote that one function in our JavaScript file (loaded after jQuery UI) to make it accept GET/POST as another option.

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._initSource = function() {
    var array, url,
        that = this;
    if ( $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
        array = this.options.source;
        this.source = function( request, response ) {
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter( array, request.term ) );
        };
    } else if ( typeof this.options.source === "string" ) {
        url = this.options.source;
        /*added*/ var httpMethod = this.options.type ? this.options.type : 'GET';
        this.source = function( request, response ) {
            if ( that.xhr ) {
                that.xhr.abort();
            }
            that.xhr = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                /*added*/ type: httpMethod,
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                },
                error: function() {
                    response( [] );
                }
            });
        };
    } else {
        this.source = this.options.source;
    }
};
```

I THINK it solves problems mentioned by other people above without breaking anything else:
- Editing the jQuery UI file directly would make upgrading jQuery UI a pain, and prevent you from using Google APIs to host your jQuery files
- $.ajaxSetup would affect every autocomplete or ajax call across our product
- Writing a $.post and passing it in as a function is cool, but a lot of typing if you use dozens of autocompletes across your site.

Comment: Modifying the source means you'll have trouble upgrading to the next version.

Comment: Fortunately, functions in JavaScript are mutable, so you don't have to. But any changes to that particular function would indeed be lost if a new version of jQuery changed it, though. Which is why you wouldn't want to use this strategy in more than the rarest of circumstances.