# Allowing Json Get without using Return(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) (To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet. error)

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I want to use a javascript uploader in my C# project. The javascript gets loaded in the master page, and in the partial view where I want the uploader to be I have the following code:

```
   <a class="upload" href="/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/StoreFile/97?Entity=Note&amp;Field=File">uploadfile</a>
```

However, when I click the button I get an '"This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." error. The same kind of question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350921/asp-net-mvc-2-failed-with-jquery-ajax-response). However, as a solution something like the following is given:

```
 return Json(new { mymsg = "my msg" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Where adding JsonRequerstBehavior.AllowGet solves the problem.

In my C# ActionResult that calls the PartialView in which I Want to add this I have this as a return:

```
return PartialView("CreateNotePartial", Model);
```

I also tried:

```
<%$.post('/blag/JSON', function (data) {%>
    <a class="upload" href="/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/StoreFile/97?Entity=Note&amp;Field=File">uploadfile
        </a>
 <%});%>
```

but that did not work.

I can not add the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. How can this be made to work without this .AllowGet?

Comment: Do you have to return a partial view, or json?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, maybe it will help others too.

```
public JsonResult AppleAppSiteAssociation()
{
        string json = "{\"applinks\": {\"apps\": [],\"details\": [] }}";
        JsonResult res = new JsonResult();
        res.Data = json;
        res.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return res;
}
```