# Does jquery ui autocomplete use POST or GET while source made by XHR?

Tags: php, post, get, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I prefered to use ajax with POST. And prepare php pages to accept only POST requests from client. I begin to use jquery ui autocomplete. And get records over 
`source:"action.php";`
How ui handles `source:` while querying server? And is it secure against classic post request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery ui by default uses GET and the default parameter is 'term' therefore it can be received using `$_GET['term']`

You can also see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512607/how-do-i-set-jquery-autocomplete-to-post-instead-of-get) if you want to change GET to POST

Answer (score 1):

In pretty much any recent browser, open developer tools (usually F12), go to the "Net" panel (net in firefox, similar in other browsers). Initiate a autocomplete (type something into the box autocomplete is attached to) and you can see the network request which will usually show "GET" or "POST".